# Theorem 8, Section 3.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations, independence

> Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $V$ into $W$. Then $T$ is non-singular$\iff$If $S\subseteq V$ is linearly independent, then $T(S)$ is linearly independent. In other word, $T$ preserve linear independent set.

**My attempt:** ($\Rightarrow$) Let $S\subseteq V$ be independent. We need to show $T(S)\subseteq T(V)$ is independent. Let $\{y_1,…,y_n\}\subseteq T(S)$. By definition of set, $y_i\neq y_j$, if $i\neq j$. If $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i \cdot_W y_i =0_W$. Since $\{y_1,…,y_n\}\subseteq T(S)$, we have $\forall i\in J_n$, $\exists x_i\in S$ such that $T(x_i)=y_i$. We claim $x_i\neq x_j$, if $i\neq j$. Assume towards contradiction, $\exists i,j\in J_n$ such that $i\neq j$ and $x_i=x_j$. Then $T(x_i)=T(x_j)=y_i=y_j$. Thus we reach contradiction. So $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i \cdot_W y_i$ $=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i \cdot_W T(x_i)$ $=\sum_{i=1}^n T(c_i \cdot_V x_i)$ $= T(\sum_{i=1}^nc_i \cdot_V x_i) =0_W$. Since $T$ is non-singular/injective, $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i \cdot_V x_i=0_V$. Since $\{x_1,…,x_n\}\subseteq S$ and $S$ is independent, we have $c_i=0_F$, $\forall i \in J_n$. Hence $T(S)$ is independent.

($\Leftarrow$) $\{0_V\}\subseteq N_T$. We need to show $\{0_V\}=N_T$. Assume towards contradiction, $\{0_V\}\subset N_T$. Then $\exists x\in N_T$ such that $x\neq 0_V$. It’s easy to check, $\{x\}$ is independent. By hypothesis, $T(\{x\})=\{T(x)\}$ is independent. But $T(x)=0_W$ is dependent. Thus we reach contradiction. **Is my proof better version of Hoffman’s proof?**

There is a subtle difference between Hoffman’s and my proof. In former case, Hoffman’s use injective condition twice (first in $T(\alpha_i)\neq T(\alpha_j)$, if $i\neq j$ and second in $N_T=\{0_V\}$). IMO, Hoffman’s proof is not the most “ideal” way to show set, $T(S)$, is independent. My proof use injective condition once ($N_T=\{0_V\}$).

Comment: Did you mean "Assume towards contradiction, $\{0_V\} \subsetneq N_T$" (`\subsetneq` rather than `\subseteq`)?

Comment: @aschepler yes. Thanks for pointing that out.